# Automatically calculating and filling excel missing values based on previous and next available data

Tags: vba, excel, average, missing-data

I'm doing eye tracking study, but the eye tracker did not always catch the eye. One excel file has ~30k-40k rows and I would like to fill the missing values with average of the previous available and next available data points. But doing it manually would take forever.

I attached an example of the table. So the missing values in the X column should be: 359.5 or rounded to 360. And Y column missing values should be 134.

Additionally, if possible, to add controlling mechanism that it would only fill the missing values if there are maximum of N values in row. The idea behind is that if the eye tracker didn't catch the eye for short periods then it's okay to calculate the average that way, but if it's for longer periods then it would not be correct.

[image: Excel table example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond locating the blank cells in columns X and Y, this is just simple maths.

```
Option Explicit

Sub missingGazePoints()
    Dim blnk As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For Each blnk In .Columns("X:Y").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            blnk = blnk.End(xlUp).Value2 + _
                  (blnk.End(xlDown).Value2 - blnk.End(xlUp).Value2) / _
                  (blnk.End(xlDown).Row - blnk.End(xlUp).Row)
        Next blnk
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that I have filled every missing point in a linear manner; not used a static average for all missing points.
[image]

**Addendum: Working with Arrays**

Looping through rows with repetitive worksheet lookup is going to slow things down; possibly to the point of a crash. Stuffing all of the values (including blanks) into a 2-D variant array and performing all processing within memory before returning the values to the worksheet will speed things up¹.

```
Sub qwuirwqwq()
    Dim rsz As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim vals As Variant, bd As Double, ed As Double

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit  'uncomment this line when you have finished debugging
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False        'uncomment this line when you have finished debugging

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        With .Cells(2, "X").Resize(Application.Min(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row - 1, _
                                                   .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row - 1), 2)
            vals = .Cells.Value2

            For x = LBound(vals, 1) + 1 To UBound(vals, 1)
                If vals(x, 1) = vbNullString Then
                    y = x + 1
                    Do While vals(y, 1) = vbNullString
                        y = y + 1
                    Loop
                    vals(x, 1) = vals(x - 1, 1) + _
                                (vals(y, 1) - vals(x - 1, 1)) / (y - x + 1)
                End If
                If vals(x, 2) = vbNullString Then
                    y = x + 1
                    Do While vals(y, 2) = vbNullString
                        y = y + 1
                    Loop
                    vals(x, 2) = vals(x - 1, 2) + _
                                (vals(y, 2) - vals(x - 1, 2)) / (y - x + 1)
                End If
            Next x

            .Cells = vals
            ReDim vals(0)
        End With
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Note the 'helper' **appTGGL** sub procedure that temporarily suspends various environment settings that tax processing until processing has completed.

You can also gain some benefits (execution speed, reduced file size) by saving your workbook as an .XLSB instead of an .XLSM.

---

¹ <sub>I ran the latter memory-based routine through 300,000 rows with ~16,000 blanks cells in 0.6 seconds on a tablet with an i5 and 8Gbs. Yes... that's correct. zero-point-six-seconds.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. It does the trick, although as I have 30000+ rows, then it's really slow. After like an hour of calculating excel finally crashed. :) Also, thanks for the linear calculation, actually that's even better.

Now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to exclude more than 20 blanks in a row.

Comment: I'll have a think on doing this in a 2-D variant array so that all processing is in memory. That is the best solution for any looped processing greater than a couple thousand rows.

Comment: In the interim,see [VBA Best Practices - Switch off properties during macro execution](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-properties-during-macro-execution).